# ¿Como auto completar el listado de lugares del mapa con libreria Vue Geocoder, VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

Actualmente tengo la siguiente función:

```
 codeAddress(){
         Vue.$geocoder.setDefaultMode('address');      // this is default
          var addressObj = {
              address_line_1: '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway',
              address_line_2: '',
              city:           '',
              state:          'CA',               // province also valid
              zip_code:       '',            // postal_code also valid
              country:        ''
          }
          Vue.$geocoder.send(addressObj, response => { console.log(response) });
        },
```

En dicha función efectivamente me retorna la informacion de la direccion ingresada, ejemplo me devuelve esto en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como puedo hacer para que al momento de ir escribiendo vaya filtrando las direcciones, asi como se nota en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No se si esto valga como respuesta, pero yo he estado en la misma situación que tu probando librerías y librerías, hasta que encontré esta que es muy buena.

[vue2-google-maps](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps#readme) esto trae un componente llamado: **auto complete** que con tan solo llamarlo hace toda la funcionalidad que necesitas. Aparte de auto completar también te devuelve la información básica del lugar.

Nota: No falta decir que tiene integración completa con la API de google maps.

Espero te sirva la información y si esto no es considerado como respuesta igual espero haberte apoyado. Saludos.